# Get share link of multiple files in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I'd like to put the share links to my files in Drive in a spreadsheet to make them easier to share. Is it possible to get the link to all files without going to each file individually?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get share link of multiple files in Google Drive to put in spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88769/get-share-link-of-multiple-files-in-google-drive-to-put-in-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 1):

You can link a specific folder in your drive by right clicking it, hitting share and then hitting "**get shareable link**"  . This will allow users with the link to see all the items in the folder in a nice drive style view