# Is there a way to get multiple share links from Google Drive in order?

Tags: google-drive, google-sheets, sharing

I have 100s of files on my Google Drive where the files are sorted by name. All I want is the share link of each file in the order they appear in Google Drive.

I tried selecting all these files inside the folder and then click Share but it doesn't respect the order of the files as they are displayed.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a brief description of your search / research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Related: [What is the the default order of the links returned by “Get sharable links” on Google Drive?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/101797/88163)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by writing a [script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) that uses `DriveApp` to retrieve the names of files and URLs in the folder and sorts the list by filename.

See the [listFileInfoBySubFolder](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/58260211?msgid=59109735) script for sample code.